# Nesting pseudo classes in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i'm trying to access the last occurrence of an element and within that element the first occurrence of another element.  So here I'm trying to access the last article tag and the first p tag following that.

```
    <div class = "wrapper">
        <article class = "article-info">
            <h3>Test1</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </article>
        <article class = "article-info">
            <h3>Test2</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </article>
        <article class = "article-info">
            <h3>Test3</h3>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </article>
    <div/>
```

I know I can access the last article by using 'last-child', but is it possible to nest another pseudo-classes to access the first p element? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:last-of-type` and `:first-of-type`. This will work even if there are elements after the last `article` or before first `p` tag

```css
.wrapper article:last-of-type p:first-of-type {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article class="article-info">
    <h3>Test1</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="article-info">
    <h3>Test2</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </article>
  <article class="article-info">
    <h3>Test3</h3>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </article>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div/>
```